# Can a '.org' be a subdomain of a '.com'?

Tags: subdomain

My site, perisys.com, is on a shared server. I have a number of .com subdomains that are invoked by entering the domain-name.com. For example, as xyz.com and not xyz.perisys.com.

However, I also have a domain-name.org that I'd like to invoke as if it were another domain-name.com.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "invoke"? Redirect? Or DNS entry?

Comment: a .org cannot be a subdomain of another root domain, but is that what you are really asking?

Comment: You've tagged this "subdomain" but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with subdomains. Did you read the tag description?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using apache, you can just add `ServerAlias` to your virtual host, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

One web server a can server multiple domains regardless of the root domain (e.g. '.com' or '.org').  If you use SSL you will need to get a multi-domain SSL certificate if you want a single website to serve multiple domains.